# Feedback wanted on Windows Phone 8 app to organize information

Tags: apps, organization

I need more feedback on an app of mine. The app currently only exists for Windows Phone 8 and up, but I'm thinking about porting it to other platforms.

The app lets you organize knowledge and information into projects and subjects, take notes, write summaries, combine summaries into longer texts, prepare for lectures, etc. The app has got a 4.5 out of 5 star rating here in the Norwegian store where people say it's really helpful, especially in a school context.

You can download the app from [here](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=611c36ab-db53-40e2-b1b2-043899bbe6bc). Please let me know what you think of it.

Comment: I'd start by also targeting Windows Phone 7.x, for a start :) (especially as it would also work on Windows Phone 8.0, and may just be a project configuration setting)

Comment: Guys, don't know. But I think it is kind of Off Topic here. But sure they will close in StackOveflow. What about we create a chat room instead?

Comment: I'll try to get a wp7 version running, perhaps we could create a chat room yeah

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about soliciting feedback and not a problem with Windows Phone.